# Checking if file or directory exists with -e flag [perl]

Tags: perl

It is probably a silly mistake, but I can't seem to understand why it does it. I wrote the following script which iterates over the lines of one file and inserts them into the other file only if the line (which is actually a path), is not a valid path.

```
open(my $fh_dst, '>>', $dst) or die
open(my $fh_src, '<', $src) or die;
while (my $file = <$fh_src>) {
    chmod($file);
    print $fh_dst $file unless(-e $file);
}
close ($fh_src);
close ($fh_dst);
```

It does insert the paths into the other file, but for some reason, if I go to the Linux command line and do `ls -la` on one of the paths, it shows me that the directory or the file exists. I made sure that `-e` works also for directories, so it is not it. What could be the problem?

Comment: Trailing newlines are probably screwing things up. You're not `chomp`ing your input.

Comment: Also, from `chmod`: "_chmod LIST --> ... The first element of
            the list must be the numeric mode ..._", which it isn't.  So it's not right right there.  Why do you use `chmod`?

Comment: You should know to `use strict; use warnings;` by now.
Also you are missing a `;`at the end of the first line of code.

Answer (score 1):

`chomp` is needed to remove the line feed that terminates the line you've read from the file. Essentially you were checking if `file␊` exists, and it doesn't. I think you meant to call `chomp`, but you called `chmod` instead. Fixed:

```
open(my $in_fh, '<', $in_qfn)
    or die("Can't open \"$in_qfn\": $!\n");

open(my $err_fh, '>>', $err_qfn)
    or die("Can't append to \"$err_qfn\": $!\n");

while (my $qfn = <$in_fh>) {
    chomp($qfn);
    print($err_fh "$qfn\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shawn is right its the chomp and corrects the chmod, testing it against a file called DUET.pl (protein modelling script). Essentially "DUET.pl\n" does not exist. You also need to add an exists statement on the "chmod" command otherwise it will throw an error if the file isn't present.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $input = '/Users/michaelg/Desktop/test.txt';
my $test_output = '/Users/michaelg/Desktop/out.txt';

    open(my $fh_dst, '>>', $test_output) or die "$!";
    open(my $fh_src, '<', $input) or die "$!";
    while (my $file = <$fh_src>) {
        chomp $file;
        chmod (0755, $file) if -e $file;
        print $fh_dst $file . "\n", unless -e $file;
    }
    close ($fh_src);
    close ($fh_dst);
__DATA__
```

**The file test.txt contents are a path to file DUET.pl. DUET.pl exists in the said location**
/Users/michaelg/Desktop/DUET.pl

**With chomp, output file,**

(blank)

**Without chomp, i.e. # chomp $file, output file (plus error),** 
/Users/michaelg/Desktop/DUET.pl

Furthermore, with chomp (shell),

```
ls -l /Users/michaelg/Desktop/DUET.pl
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 michaelg  staff  xxx  4 Dec xx:xx DUET.pl
Without chomp,
-rwx------@ 1 michaelg  staff  xxx  4 Dec xx:xx DUET.pl
```

Note xx:xx timestamp removed

Comment: Re "*You also need to add an exists statement on the "chmod" command otherwise it will throw an error if the file isn't present.*", No, it will simply return false and set `$!` to `ENOENT` (unless you add `use autodie;`). This is *exactly* what `-e` does if the file doesn't exist, so the check you added is entire superfluous.

Comment: What would make sense is `chmod(0755, $file) or print $fh_dst "$file\n";`.